# Selenium IDE: Save a specific part of a string in a variable

Tags: selenium-ide

I would like to store the "FHCS79" out of "Your booking number is FHCS79" in a variable.

```
storeText css=h2 string<br>
echo ${string}
```

What is the smoothest way?

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839002/4855333
This is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you remove/ignore the first part of your string.  in this case "Your booking number is " will be consistent, that way any remaining value (of any length) can be considered the booking number.

```
//---- remove only char in "Your booking number is "   
str = str.substring(23,(string.length));
```

Below is a synopsis of how the function works so you can expand it in the future

```
//---- remove first and last char of str    
str = str.substring(1,((string.length)-1));

//---- remove only first char    
str = str.substring(1,(string.length));

//---- remove only last char    
str = str.substring(0,(string.length));
```

An alternative is to use Slenium IDE's native Globbing pattern.  Its not Quite as flexible but follows a similar pattern
Further information on how to use "Globbing patterns" is available [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#globbing-patterns)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ECiurleo. Could you please help me put it in a Selenium IDE context since I'm quite a noob when it comes to coding? :). Would really appreciate it!

Comment: I have added details of an alternative method to do the same thing but looks simpler.  To use my above you "just" need to add it as a Regex in the Value field.  If you are a new new user, it might be more complicated than is needed :)